# center img inside span

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center an image inside a span. But it doesn't work.

Here is a link to my code:  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4eobp3g2/)

```
<div>
    <label>
        <span>left span that can have more than one line</span>
        <span><img class="redcross" /></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

the class "redcross" is what I want to center vertically

can someone help me?

Comment: Honestly, your code is dirty, what you are trying to accomplish can be achieved in few lines of code

Comment: Actually you are not clear with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `right` and `margin-right`, Add `position: absolute` and `margin-top: -11px`

```
.redcross {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #94B548;
  /*background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);*/
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22iso-8859-1%22%3F%3E%3C!DOCTYPE%20svg%20PUBLIC%20%22-%2F%2FW3C%2F%2FDTD%20SVG%201.1%2F%2FEN%22%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FGraphics%2FSVG%2F1.1%2FDTD%2Fsvg11.dtd%22%3E%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Layer_1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20%20width%3D%2214px%22%20height%3D%2214px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2014%2014%22%20style%3D%22enable-background%3Anew%200%200%2014%2014%3B%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%3Cpolygon%20style%3D%22fill%3A%23FFFFFF%3B%22%20points%3D%2211.949%2C3.404%207%2C8.354%202.05%2C3.404%20-0.071%2C5.525%207%2C12.596%2014.07%2C5.525%20%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
  -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -11px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4eobp3g2/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Change your **css**:

```
.button {
    position:absolute;
  width:24px;
  height:100%;
  top:3px;
  right:0;
}
```

**top 0 to 3px;**

Comment: but when I resize the screen so that I have multi lines, than the image is not vertical centered

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure Mr. Alien means well. But I was there too. Anyway, a simple steps to get what you are looking for:

Change your `.button` class to

```
.button {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width:24px;
}
```

You see, the `vertical-align` property doesn't quite work how some people think it does. It only affects inline elements. Furthermore, it aligns it vertical relative to the current line. So, in other words, if you were to say have more than one line on a block of text to the left and a button to the right, this wouldn't work.

You would need to wrap that block of text in an `inline-block` and adjust the `line-height` accordingly to get this same effect for it to be vertically aligned. Essentially, the two elements (block of text and img) would be behaving like text. This is important to understand especially in a screen responsive environment.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with **flexbox**.
It's a very recent feature but very useful.

Just add this lines to your `.button` class.

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

Here you have it [working](https://jsfiddle.net/4eobp3g2/4/). The green circle gets deformed but I would consider using a fixed image instead the border-radius.

Here you can see its [browsers compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)